# Cannot enqueue array value

Tags: c, queue

I create a `Queue` that includes a two dimensional array, the size of every element of that array is 2. An Exception occurs when I enqueue a 2-size array in the queue.

The following is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define size 1000

typedef struct Queue {
    int *data[2];
    int front;
    int rear;
}Queue;

void init(Queue *q)
{
    q->front=0;
    q->rear=0;
}

void Enqueue(Queue *q,int *value)
{
    if(q->rear==size)
        return ;

    q->data[q->rear++]=value;
}

void main()
{
    Queue q[1];

    init(q);

    int a[10][2];

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        a[i][0]=i;
        a[i][1]=i*2+1;      
        Enqueue(q,a[i]);    
    }   
}
```

Comment: I very much doubt you're getting an exception in C, but please add exactly what error you're getting. Similarly, what happens if you run this in a debugger?

Comment: you mean    int data[size];  ?

Comment: The error out put is:
'Queue_LinkList_Stack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Queue_LinkList_Stack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\f_pbrc09.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Queue_LinkList_Stack.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
First-chance exception at 0x013c1418 in Queue_LinkList_Stack.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0112ea00.
Unhandled exception at 0x013c1418 in Queue_LinkList_Stack.exe:

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least a couple of issues:

```
typedef struct Queue {
   int *data[2];
```

This is not a pointer to a two-dimensional array of ints, which I assume was what was intended. It is an array of two int pointers. 
For a 2D array of 1000 entries of arrays with two elements, you probably wanted:

```
typedef struct Queue {
   int data[size][2];
```

Then, when you call Enqueue(), copy in the array of two ints into the appropriate entry indicated by rear:

```
void Enqueue(Queue *q,int value[2])
{
    if(q->rear==size)
        return ;

    memcpy(q->data[q->rear], value, sizeof(q->data[q->rear]));
    q->rear++;
}
```

This solution will make a fixed array. If you want the array to be built dynamically it is a little more complicated as you need to malloc/calloc the memory and then free it when done.

Comment: @LidongGuo In the call to Enqueue()? Right you are, I misread that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 *I create a Queue that includes a two dimensional array*
```

No you just create a pointer array in onw dimensional  by `int *data[2];`

If you want create a Quene that include  a two demensional array , `it will be int data[size][size_anoter]`

However, you didn't need I two dimensional . In `void Enqueue(Queue *q,int *value)` function , you pass the address from a[i] to data[i] . So you only need a  big enough pointer array ;\

```
int * data[size];
```

Besides , It is better if you can define `size` as `SIZE`.

Answer (score 0):

probably, Feel like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size 1000

typedef struct Queue {
    int (**data)[2];
    int front;
    int rear;
} Queue;

void init(Queue *q){
    q->front=0;
    q->rear=0;
    q->data = malloc(size*sizeof(int (*)[2]));
}

void Enqueue(Queue *q,int (*value)[2]){
    if(q->rear==size)
        return ;

    q->data[q->rear++]=value;
}

int main(){
    Queue q[1];

    init(q);

    int a[10][2];

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        a[i][0]=i;
        a[i][1]=i*2+1;
        Enqueue(q, &a[i]);
    }
    //printf("%d\n", (*q->data[0])[1]);
    return 0;
}
```